# ValueError trying to install Pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I downloaded the get-pip.py from here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Its in a .py file in my computer but when I run the code I get:

ValueError: base85 overflow in hunk starting at byte 23770.

This is from a Raise handler in a Try and Except statement in the code on line 65-ish. What can be done about this?

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/5540592 to get more options

Comment: @WILL_K it doesn't seem to mention anything about that error

Comment: This error is mentioned no where so I suggested alternative solutions